# PHP: Get text separated by commas

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensinal array.. Something like this for example:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Star Trek - Viaje a las estrellas
            [country] => Venezuela, Spain, long title, poster title
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Viaje a Las Estrellas
            [country] => Venezuela
        )
)
```

I want to get te text between commas from [country] and insert each element into separate indexes, for example:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Star Trek - Viaje a las estrellas
            [country] => [0] => Venezuela
                         [1] => Spain
                         [2] => long title
                         [3] => poster title
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Viaje a Las Estrellas
            [country] => Venezuela
        )
)
```

Probably the array layout is incorrect but I just want to explain to you what I need to do. 
Note that not always [country] contains elements separated by commas, sometimes is just one single element.

How can I do it??

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) on the country element. You can use a separator of `", "`, since these are comma-separated values.

One way to do it (which is similar to how others have suggested) would be:

```
// Assuming that $data contains your multidimensional array...
for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
    if (strstr($data[$i]['country'], ', '))
    {
        $data[$i]['country'] = explode(', ', $data[$i]['country']);
    }
}
```

Also, note that you don't really need to use `strpos()`—`strstr()` works perfectly here.

Comment: strpos would be better, no + from me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `preg_split` function and a regular expression to split the string:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
    if (strpos($item['country'], ',') !== false) {  // check if string contains a comma
        $array[$key]['country'] = preg_split('/,\s*/', $item['country']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use preg_split when there's a perfectly good explode() function available?

Comment: @Paolo Bergantino: To remove possible space characters too.

Comment: Why not just include the space in the delimiter for explode()? preg_split() seems kind of like overkill here...

Comment: @htw: I don’t know where the values to process come from and whether the comma is always followed by a single space character. Using a regular expression can cover this uncertainty.

Comment: By the way: Why does everyone have such a fundamental aversion to regular expressions? Regular expressions are not in general evil.

Comment: @htw, what happens when one record has no spaces, and the next record has multiple spaces?  The preg_split will work with both 'a,b' and 'a,   b'.

Comment: Sure, but I'd also say that it depends on the task at hand. If it's data that is entered manually by a user or comes from a source that the programmer doesn't ahve control over, then yes, preg_split() would be better. But otherwise, explode() fits the bill perfectly. In other words, as OIS said, use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = Array (
    0 => Array
        (
            "title" => "Star Trek - Viaje a las estrellas",
            "country" => "Venezuela, Spain, long title, poster title"
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            "title" => "Viaje a Las Estrellas",
            "country" => "Venezuela"
        )
);
$res = array();    
    foreach($a as $k => $v){
        foreach($v as $key => $value){
            switch($key){
                case "country":                                
                    $r = split(",", $value); 
                    foreach($r as $index => $val){
                        $res[$k][$key][$index] = trim($val);
                    }
                  break;
                default:
                    $res[$k][$key] = $value;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($res);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Star Trek - Viaje a las estrellas
            [country] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Venezuela
                    [1] => Spain
                    [2] => long title
                    [3] => poster title
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Viaje a Las Estrellas
            [country] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Venezuela
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Note that, since you are exploding the string using just ',' as a delimiter, there are leading spaces in three of the values in the country array.